The await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(memoryStream); never continues
The AspNetCore.Components.Forms.IBrowserFile file call to await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(memoryStream); never continues.
public async Task<string> VinImgRecon(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.IBrowserFile file)
{
    string vqAccessCode = "access-code";
    string reconUrl = @"https://www.recognition.ws/vinbarcode/v2?accesscode=" + vqAccessCode + "&vindecode=TRUE";

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                formData.Add(new StreamContent(memoryStream));
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(reconUrl, formData);
                string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseString;
            }
        }
    }
}

Some of this code came from copilot AI. It looks reasonable. Yet we never get the return responseString.
We tried various break points.

It turns out that the OpenReadSream needs to have a max size value greater than the file to be read.
await file.OpenReadStream(10240000).CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

